# Different return values dependent on value of generic constant

Tags: generics, rust

Let's consider a function like this:

```rust
fn test<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    if N == 1 {
        [0.0_f64; 1]
    } else if N == 2 {
        [1.0_f64; 2]
    } else {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the compiler would evaluate the value of `N` at compile time. If this is the case, the `if` statement could also be evaluated at compile time, thus the right type should be returned since `[0.0_f64; 1]` is only returned if `N == 1` and `[1.0_f64; 2]` is only returned if `N == 2`.

Now, when i try to compile this code, the compiler fails, basically telling me that the dimensions of the returned arrays are wrong since they do not explicitly have `N` as length.

I do realize, that i could implement this specific example as

```rust
fn test<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    match N {
        1 => { [0.0_f64; N] },
        2 => { [1.0_f64; N] },
        _ => { panic!("Invalid value {}", N) },
    }
}
```

But that does not work in my actual code, since that uses different functions with fixed array sizes for the different branches.

Is there a way to do this at all? Maybe using something like the `#![cfg]` makro?

To clarify my why my problem does not work, let's write this out:

```rust
fn some_fct() -> [f64; 1] {
    [0.0_f64; 1]
}
fn some_other_fct() -> [f64; 2] {
    [1.0_f64; 2]
}

fn test<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    match N {
        1 => some_fct(),
        2 => some_other_fct(),
        _ => {
            panic!("Invalid value {}", N)
        }
    }
}
```

And I cannot really write `some_fct()` and `some_other_fct()` to return with generic sizes due to other restrictions in the program structure.

Comment: if you do not post your original problem it is difficult. usually you could match and decide on the filling parameter and then always return the array N sized.

Comment: "But that does not work in my actual code, since that uses different functions with fixed array sizes for the different branches." I don't see why it should work with the match. You are doing something wrong, xy problem, please include [mcve]

Comment: You can with `unsafe` and transmute (`transmute_copy()`, to be precise). But in general, Rust does not evaluates control flow while deciding if the size in appropriate. In `min_const_generics` (i.e. without `generic_const_exprs`) it does not evaluate any thing.

Comment: @Stargateur It is not returning `[...; 1]` but `[...; N]`.

Comment: @Stargateur In the match i use `[...; N]` to generate the arrays, which is recognized by the compiler to yield the correct array size. This does compile correctly, unlike the first example. The functions i have to use in my actual code have to have fixed return values though, unfortunately. I have edited the original post to include an other example that hopefully clarifies things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with a generic trait:

```
trait Test<const N: usize> {
    fn test() -> [f64; N];
}
```

Then you implement it for a zero sized type:

```
struct T;

impl Test<1> for T {
    fn test() -> [f64; 1] {
        return [0.0_f64; 1];
    }
}

impl Test<2> for T {
    fn test() -> [f64; 2] {
        return [1.0_f64; 2];
    }
}
```

The drawback is that calling it is a bit cumbersome:

```
fn main() {
    dbg!(<T as Test<1>>::test());
    dbg!(<T as Test<2>>::test());
}
```

But as @eggyal comments below, you can add a generic function with a well-written bound to get your required syntax:

```
fn test<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N]
where
    T: Test<N>
{
    T::test()
}
fn main() {
    dbg!(test::<1>());
    dbg!(test::<2>());
}
```

Now, you don't have the behavior of "`panic!` when a wrong `N` is used". Consider that a feature instead of a limitation: if you use a wrong `N` your code will fail to compile instead of panic at runtime.

If you really want the `panic!()` behavior you could get it using the unstable feature of `#![feature(specialization)]`, just adding `default` to this impl:

```
impl<const N: usize> Test<N> for T {
    default fn test() -> [f64; N] {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

But that feature is explicitly marked as incomplete, so I would not count on it, yet.

Comment: That is actually really smart. Good thinking, thanks!

Comment: Actually you can get the generic `test` wrapper function working without specialisation, [using a `where T: Test<N>` bound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31bc4cfd1d667c0ac0104b0120357233).  cc @LateinCecker

Comment: @eggyal: Of course! How didn't I see it? If you don't mind I'll update the answer with this code.

Comment: Of course, please do :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that is not particularly clever, but is easy to understand and resembles the original:

```
fn test<const N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    match N {
        1 => some_fct().as_slice().try_into().unwrap(),
        2 => some_other_fct().as_slice().try_into().unwrap(),
        _ => {
            panic!("Invalid value {}", N)
        }
    }
}
```

Although the code looks like it checks array sizes at run time, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9znaKa9aG) shows that rustc/LLVM is able to reason that `[f64; N].as_slice().try_into()` always succeeds in coercing the array-turned-slice to `[f64; N]`. Generated code for `test<1>` and `test<2>` thus contains no checks or panic, and `test<N>` for `N>2` just panics unconditionally due to the panic in the catch-all match arm.